# how to check if a field exist in facebook graph api using python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As facebook graph API uses JSON format to show data.I want to get all the books name liked by my friends using python and facebook Graph API but my program stops when any of my friend have not read any book. So please give me a way to check if field exist or not.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

## Print name of friends and books liked by them. Id and access token are given by user.

import requests 
import json

## base_url = raw_input("Enter the id : ")

## ACCESS_TOKEN = raw_input("Paste here the access token : ")

base_url = '6365047697172'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'CAACEdEose0cBANCFK1KuoSP6gZCOsmqZC17v1vZCmWrA5FW16pKs7iUoz2ZAIliZCFnIj32rZCVZB7KAh0aa6dqLudLoYZBI6Gs30VlZAY2JP7ZCzM0TpBCneRmKrpDT2PIFxxdScNbZASsKYPIkUXSpPKKsNCemKEuGBZB3uPXNiy4bW0DMKKQeuhQRns5xuXCDYNeVtyh17PZB09lgZBoipW2'
base_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + base_url

fields ='friends{books,name}'
url = '%s?fields=%s&access_token=%s' % \
    (base_url, fields, ACCESS_TOKEN,)

def get_books():
    """
        Returns the list of posts on my timeline
    """

```
parameters = {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN}
r = requests.get(url)
result = json.loads(r.text)
friends =  result["friends"]

frnd_data = friends["data"]
for frnd_name in frnd_data:
    print frnd_name['name']
    frnd_book = frnd_name['books'] #error when there is no field name books
    f_b_name = frnd_book["data"]
    for b_name in f_b_name:
        print b_name['name']
```

get_books()

Answer (score 0):

If you use the json module in python, the method load (or loads) maps that json to a dictionary.  Then you can treat it just like a dictionary which means you can just ask it if it contains the value using the following code

```
if field in json:
    ...
```

I hope that helps.